# Adding scale to currency formatted numbers with String.Format

Tags: c#, .net, string, format, currency-formatting

I'm attempting to format currency values using a scaling factor.
I'm able to do this with normal decimal numbers, eg: `string.Format("{0:0,,.000 million}",123456789);` will return "123.457 million"

I'd like to be able to do this with currency values though... The standard numeric format specifier ("C") allows you to set precision, but no scaling. For example, `string.Format("{0:C3}",123456789)` will return "$123,456,789.000", but I haven't been able to figure out how to return "$123.457 million".

Is there a formatting string that solves this?

Comment: Please show what you tried so far

Comment: Do you expect all the values to be returned in `Millions` always?

Comment: Does your solution require the formatter to solve this or cannot you not factor the value before passing it into `string.Format`?

Comment: I've tried things like `string.Format({0:C3,, millions},123456789)` for example, but it appears that the "C" specifier isn't meant to be mixed with custom stuff. The "millions" is arbitrary - I want to be able to scale it to thousands/millions/billions etc. Currently I'm having to factor it myself before formatting, but I'd prefer to use the formatter to solve the problem if possible.